# redisで文章検索するには

Tags: redis

redisにコメント文を格納して、全文検索したいと思っています。

redisで扱える型はStringやListなど使えますが、文字列の検索はkeyを使って行うようです。
そもそもredisの使い方やredis自体を使うことがいけないのかもしれません。

もし、redisを使ってのコメント文の全文検索を行うことができるということならば、格納方法と検索方法をご教示お願いします。参考になるURLでも結構です。

何卒よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Redis に値を検索する機能は無いです。
全文検索なら Elasticsearch 向きの課題だと思います。